# runtime error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$

Tags: java, sqlite, scala, jdbc, slick

I am trying to use Scala to create and query an SQLite db. I found out that slick is a good library for this.
My code is:

```
import scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.simple._
import org.sqlite._

object driver {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val db2 : org.sqlite.JDBC = null
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:~/my_db.sqlite", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")
  } 
}
```

~/my_db.sqlite does not exist. It is just an empty file.

I am compiling and running in the following way:

```
$ scalac -cp "libs/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"  driver.scala
$ scala driver
$ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at driver$.main(driver.scala:7)
    at driver.main(driver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: The ClassNotFoundException is clear: unable to find scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver class in classpath (libs/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:libs/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar)

Comment: But that class is in libs/slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar . And I don't get a compile error in line 1, when i import it.

Comment: You specifiing a driver in (driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC") has it implementation?

Comment: yes, it comes from sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar